# Determine what line user is editing in textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to be able to determine what line the user is editing in a multi-line text-box.

So could anyone suggest how i get the line number that the user is editing.

Also, is it possible to have textboxes side by side which when the user takes a new line in one, we can programatically take a new line on the other one?

Comment: you can do lines.Count() to get total lines, also what about if there are spaces or blanks between lines..? furthermore.. what have you tried on your own..? I am voting to close because you have not done enough research on your own

Comment: I have looked through the whole of stack overflow and the c sharp documentation and can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`label_currentLine.Text = Textbox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(Textbox1.SelectionStart) + 1`

Plus 1 because index starts at 0.